# How to change the value of an XML node based on another node on the same level?

Tags: c#, xml

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<gallery>
  <name>Rosie's Gallery</name>
  <image>
    <order>0</order>
    <url>images/HappyIcon.jpg</url>
    <title>Happy</title>
  </image>
  <image>
    <order>1</order>
    <url>images/SickIcon.jpg</url>
    <title>Sick</title>
  </image>
</gallery>
```

If I have the url value available to me, how would I go about changing the corresponding title value? I've been trying to figure it out but I am hitting a road block.

Comment: What code have you tried so far, and what goes wrong?

Comment: Why do you tag this question with WPF?

Comment: Well I was trying to use something like currentDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("image[url='" + imageLocation + "']", "new url value here"); 

but it didn't like the path value. I was hoping someone would know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xmlstr));
string url="images/SickIcon.jpg";

var image = xDoc.Descendants("image")
                .Where(x => x.Element("url").Value == url)
                .First();
image.Element("title").Value = "Renamed Value";
```

Comment: Careful: This code will throw an exception if; there is no element with a name url (null reference exception), no matching url to Value (null reference exception) or there is no element with a name title (null reference exception).

Answer (score 1):

If you use LinqToXml it would look like:
(assuming you have no duplicate urls)

```
var urlValue = "images/SickIcon.jpg";
var newTitle = "New Title";

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("<uri to file>");
XElement xImage = XDocument.root
  .Descendants("image")
  .FirstOrDefault(element => element.Elements("url").Any()
                             && element.Elements("title").Any()
                             && element.Elements("url").First().Value == urlValue);

if (xImage != null)
{
  xImage.Elements("title").First().Value = newTitle;
}
```

Comment: this works as well! awesome! thank you so much! I'd rate them both as the answer but I wound up using the other one and it won't let me choose both I think